# How to identify 'main' ubuntu repository apps

Tags: software-center

How can I know that I'm downloading an app from 'main' instead of 'universe' repo?

How are they identified in Ubuntu Software Center?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need The Force,

Look for the Source,

It's in the package's Details section, of course.

Now to ride away on a horse.

MAIN:

[image: Main]

UNIVERSE:

[image: Universe]

Comment: Confused me that now many come from snapcraft.io. These snaps are as good as 'main' right?

Comment: Snaps are different in many ways. I'm not sure what you consider "good". Also, unrelated follow-up questions are discouraged. Open a new question.

Comment: Thank you. I mean: are snaps considered 'main' respositories? I try to  understand when a piece of software is from 'main', when from 'universe' etc. I thank your support.

Comment: That's a non-trivial question. Again, please open a new question.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `show` option of `apt`:

> **show (apt-cache(8))**
>
> Show information about the given package(s) including its dependencies, installation and download size, sources the package is available from, the description of the packages content and much more. It can e.g. be helpful to look at this information before allowing apt(8) to remove a package or while searching for new packages to install.

```
apt show <package> | grep 'APT-Sources'
```

For example:

```
$ apt show kate | grep 'APT-Sources'
APT-Sources: http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Isn't this info available in UCS itself or anywhere else in Ubuntu?

Comment: @dm29 that I don't know :|